# Ruby sub not applying in the output file using IO.write

Tags: ruby, encoding, gsub

I have an issue about getting the same result in the output txt file that I get applying the sub method in a string. So the thing is when I apply the following code in a single string I get the \n before the capital letter in the middle of the string:

```
line3= "We were winning The Home Secretary played a
important role."
line3.sub(/(?<!^) *+(?=[A-Z])/, "\n")

=> "We were winning\nThe Home Secretary played a\n    important role."
```

But if I apply the following code the txt file that I get doesn't have any \n before the capital letter.

```
old= File.readlines("Modificado word.txt")
second= old.join

third= second.sub(/(?<!^) *+(?=[A-Z])/, "\n")

new= IO.write("new.txt", third)
```

I've tried multiple ways of encoding(surely in the wrong way) because I thought the the issue might be there but any of them worked. Even the gsub, but didn't work either.

Comment: You could debug script by printing intermediate result like this: 
`third = second.sub(/(?<!^) *+(?=[A-Z])/, "\n");
puts third` And see if `sub` works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've got the solution, I don't know why but the type of encode of the txt file is in a format that the readlines command is not even able to read, so I copied all the content in another txt file which should be created from scratch and it worked :)